# ng-bootstrap not working on initial install

Tags: angular, angular-cli, ng-bootstrap

I have just npm installed bootstrap4,font awesome, and ng-bootstrap, and I am trying some ng-bootstrap demo code. Nothing is working.

First time posting and fairly new to the Angular world. Go easy if I didn't post this in correct format or asking the question in a wrong 'area'.

I am trying to just understand the ng-bootstrap usage.

app.module.ts:

```
  import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
    import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
    import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
    import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
    import { AngularFontAwesomeModule } from 'angular-font-awesome/angular-font-awesome';
    import { NgbModule } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';

    import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
    import { CustomersModule } from './customers/customers.module';
    import { WelcomeComponent } from './welcome/welcome.component';

    @NgModule({
     declarations: [
        AppComponent,
        WelcomeComponent
     ],
     imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        HttpClientModule,
        AngularFontAwesomeModule,
        RouterModule.forRoot([
            { path: 'home', component: WelcomeComponent },
            { path: '', redirectTo: 'home', pathMatch: 'full'},
            { path: '**', redirectTo: 'home', pathMatch: 'full'}
         ]),
         CustomersModule
      ],
      bootstrap: [`enter code here`AppComponent, WelcomeComponent]
    })
    export class AppModule { }
```

app.main.html:

```
<div class="container">
  <ngb-tabset>
    <ngb-tab title="Bacon">
      <ng-template ngbTabContent>
        <p class="mt-4">Content for tab 1.
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" placement="bottom" ngbPopover="A popover in tab 1" popoverTitle="Bacon is good">
            Click me
          </button>
        </p>
      </ng-template>
    </ngb-tab>
    <ngb-tab title="Lettuce">
      <ng-template ngbTabContent>
        <p>Content for tab 2</p>
      </ng-template>
    </ngb-tab>
    <ngb-tab title="Tomatoes">
      <ng-template ngbTabContent>
        <p>Content for tab 3</p>
      </ng-template>
    </ngb-tab>
  </ngb-tabset>
</div>
```

app.component.ts:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'pm-root',
  styleUrls: ["./shared/app.css"],
  templateUrl: './app.main.html'
})
export class AppComponent {
  pageTitle: string = 'MeLo 2';
}
```

angular-cli:

```
"apps": [
    {
      "root": "src",
      "outDir": "dist",
      "assets": [
        "assets",
        "api"
      ],
      "index": "index.html",
      "main": "main.ts",
      "polyfills": "polyfills.ts",
      "test": "test.ts",
      "tsconfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
      "testTsconfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
      "prefix": "pm",
      "styles": [
        "styles.css",
        "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css",
        "../node_modules/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css"
      ],
      "scripts": [
        "../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"
      ]
    }
```

package.json:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/common": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/http": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "^4.0.0",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^1.0.0-beta.5",
    "angular-font-awesome": "^2.3.7",
    "bootstrap": "^4.0.0-alpha.6",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "popper.js": "^1.12.3",
    "rxjs": "^5.4.1",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.14"
  },
```

Error:

```
compiler.es5.js:1694 Uncaught Error: Template parse errors:
Can't bind to 'dismissible' since it isn't a known property of 'ngb-alert'.
1. If 'ngb-alert' is an Angular component and it has 'dismissible' input, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'ngb-alert' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.
3. To allow any property add 'NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component. ("
<div class="jumbotron">
  <div class="container">
    <ngb-alert type="success" [ERROR ->][dismissible]="false">
      Bootstrap is working!
    </ngb-alert>
"): ng:///AppModule/AppComponent.html@20:30
'ngb-alert' is not a known element:
1. If 'ngb-alert' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'ngb-alert' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message. ("
<div class="jumbotron">
  <div class="container">
    [ERROR ->]<ngb-alert type="success" [dismissible]="false">
      Bootstrap is working!
    </ngb-alert>
"): ng:///AppModule/AppComponent.html@20:4
Can't bind to 'value' since it isn't a known property of 'ngb-progressbar'.
1. If 'ngb-progressbar' is an Angular component and it has 'value' input, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'ngb-progressbar' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.
3. To allow any property add 'NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component. ("
  <p>
    A progress bar:
    <ngb-progressbar showValue="true" type="success" [ERROR ->][value]="65">
    </ngb-progressbar>
  </p>
"): ng:///AppModule/AppComponent.html@34:53
'ngb-progressbar' is not a known element:
1. If 'ngb-progressbar' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'ngb-progressbar' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message. ("
  <p>
    A progress bar:
    [ERROR ->]<ngb-progressbar showValue="true" type="success" [value]="65">
    </ngb-progressbar>
  </p>
"): ng:///AppModule/AppComponent.html@34:4
'ngb-tab' is not a known element:
1. If 'ngb-tab' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'ngb-tab' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message. ("
<div class="container">
  <ngb-tabset>
    [ERROR ->]<ngb-tab title="Bacon">
      <ng-template ngbTabContent>
        <p class="mt-4">Content for tab 1"): ng:///AppModule/AppComponent.html@41:4
'ngb-tab' is not a known element:
1. If 'ngb-tab' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'ngb-tab' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message. ("
      </ng-template>
    </ngb-tab>
    [ERROR ->]<ngb-tab title="Lettuce">
      <ng-template ngbTabContent>
        <p>Content for tab 2</p>
"): ng:///AppModule/AppComponent.html@50:4
'ngb-tab' is not a known element:
1. If 'ngb-tab' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'ngb-tab' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message. ("
      </ng-template>
    </ngb-tab>
    [ERROR ->]<ngb-tab title="Tomatoes">
      <ng-template ngbTabContent>
        <p>Content for tab 3</p>
"): ng:///AppModule/AppComponent.html@55:4
'ngb-tabset' is not a known element:
1. If 'ngb-tabset' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'ngb-tabset' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message. ("

<div class="container">
  [ERROR ->]<ngb-tabset>
    <ngb-tab title="Bacon">
      <ng-template ngbTabContent>
"): ng:///AppModule/AppComponent.html@40:2
    at syntaxError (compiler.es5.js:1694)
    at TemplateParser.webpackJsonp.../../../compiler/@angular/compiler.es5.js.TemplateParser.parse (compiler.es5.js:12791)
    at JitCompiler.webpackJsonp.../../../compiler/@angular/compiler.es5.js.JitCompiler._compileTemplate (compiler.es5.js:26994)
    at compiler.es5.js:26913
    at Set.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at JitCompiler.webpackJsonp.../../../compiler/@angular/compiler.es5.js.JitCompiler._compileComponents (compiler.es5.js:26913)
    at compiler.es5.js:26800
    at Object.then (compiler.es5.js:1683)
    at JitCompiler.webpackJsonp.../../../compiler/@angular/compiler.es5.js.JitCompiler._compileModuleAndComponents (compiler.es5.js:26799)
    at JitCompiler.webpackJsonp.../../../compiler/@angular/compiler.es5.js.JitCompiler.compileModuleAsync (compiler.es5.js:26728)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Read carefully the [installation guide](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/getting-started).
If your component is referenced in the root module you must write in root.module.ts

```
imports: [NgbModule.forRoot(), ...],
```

If youy component is referenced in other module you must write in module.module.ts

```
imports: [NgbModule, ...]
```

Comment: .forRoot() on  NgbModule is deprecated

Comment: it's true, I think remember that from 4.0.0 of ngb-bootstrap (actually it's the 6.x.x), but this answer has almost 2 and half years :)

Comment: i had some issue on using ngb-progressbar so i ended up on this thread  wasn't able to fix it so had to make a workaround on using regular progressbar